# Jquery Datatables: How to properly do DateTime sorting, while trying to use Ultimate DateTime sorting plugin

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I would like to render an HTML table with two columns:

1. A `DateTime` column - for example, Wednesday, March 4th 2015, 4:39:10 pm
2. A column holding string values

The `DateTime` values in the table are initially unsorted, and I need to render a view showing datetimes in sorted fashion.

The problem I have is on both the ascending sort and the descending sort:

Descending sort: (Latest date first)

To immediately give us an idea of the problem, the very latest(newest) entry I need to have displayed as the first DateTime entry, is:

**Thursday, March 5th 2015, 10:13:55 am**

Instead, this is appearing as the 123rd entry, and (correctly) followed by the other values for March 5 in descending order.

**Note**: also listed adjacent to each DateTime entry is a string entry that belongs to the second column.

```
Tuesday, January 27th 2015, 12:29:52 pm Lulus Mac Stuff 
Thursday, March 5th 2015, 10:13:55 am   Search for the Truth
Thursday, March 5th 2015, 10:09:11 am   Search for the Truth
Thursday, March 5th 2015, 10:08:02 am   Search for the Truth
```

The sorting is not happening here.

The very first entry in my HTML table was a March 4th entry as follows:

```
Wednesday, March 4th 2015, 6:21:04 pm
```

Of course, the block of March 4th entries are all neatly sorted in descending order: I show this phenomenon below:

```
    Wednesday, March 4th 2015, 6:21:04 pm   Search for the Truth  
    Wednesday, March 4th 2015, 6:20:14 pm   Search for the Truth  
    Wednesday, March 4th 2015, 6:14:38 pm   Search for the Truth
```

Can anyone point me what is going wrong? I have spent many hours on this seemingly difficult conundrum.

Here is the code that I want to correct.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    
    var tz = jstz.determine();
          var timeZoneIdentifier = tz.name();
          alert("My time zone is: " + timeZoneIdentifier);
          var mytimezone = "CST";
          
          if(timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Chicago") {
           mytimezone = "CST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/New_York"){
           mytimezone = "EST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Los_Angeles"){
           mytimezone = "PST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Denver" || timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Phoenix"){
           mytimezone = "MST";
          }
          else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Anchorage"){
           mytimezone = "AST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Adak" || timeZoneIdentifier == "Pacific/Honolulu" ){
           mytimezone = "HST";
          }
    
          $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY' );
          
          $('#example').dataTable({
           alert("entered datatable function");
           bAutoWidth: false,
            "aoColumns": [
                   { "mData": "Timestamp", "sTitle": "Timestamp " + " - " + mytimezone, "sWidth": "20%", "sType": "datetime-us" },
                         { "mData": "Location", "sTitle": "Location", "sWidth": "40%", "sType": 'string' }
                      ],
                   "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
                  "aTargets": ["column-0"],
                     "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
                      alert("in the function where the final formatting happens")
             return moment(date).format('MMM. D, h:mm A z');
            }
        }], "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]] 
                     
          });
    
   });
 
</script>
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.3.0/moment-timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://oyodev1.cloudapp.net:3000/js/libraries/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="dt-example">

<div class="container">
 <section>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>TimeZone</th>
              <th width="20%">Location</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 6:19:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 6:17:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 5:46:18 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:47:56 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
    10:08:02 am</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
    10:09:11 am</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:14:28 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:14:02 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:12:23 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
         <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 5:31:33 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
             10:09:11 am</td>
          <td >Search for the Truth</td>
        </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Tuesday, January 27th
    2015, 12:32:02 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tuesday, January 27th
    2015, 12:32:01 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr> 
  </table>

</section>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, remove `alert("entered datatable function");` , This is not a function, it's an object that is passed to the `dataTable()` function and is used to setup the data table. While this object can contain functions, putting `alert("entered datatable function");` where you have it is definitely not valid (you should see the error in the console.)

After that, re-arrange the loading order of your scripts and when you do, (**most importantly**) include `http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/sorting/datetime-moment.js`:

```js
var tz = jstz.determine();
          var timeZoneIdentifier = tz.name();
          alert("My time zone is: " + timeZoneIdentifier);
          var mytimezone = "CST";
          
          if(timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Chicago") {
           mytimezone = "CST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/New_York"){
           mytimezone = "EST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Los_Angeles"){
           mytimezone = "PST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Denver" || timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Phoenix"){
           mytimezone = "MST";
          }
          else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Anchorage"){
           mytimezone = "AST";
          } else if (timeZoneIdentifier == "America/Adak" || timeZoneIdentifier == "Pacific/Honolulu" ){
           mytimezone = "HST";
          }
    
          $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY' );
          
          $('#example').dataTable({
           bAutoWidth: false,
            "aoColumns": [
                   { "mData": "Timestamp", "sTitle": "Timestamp " + " - " + mytimezone, "sWidth": "20%", "sType": "datetime-us" },
                         { "mData": "Location", "sTitle": "Location", "sWidth": "40%", "sType": 'string' }
                      ],
                   "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
                  "aTargets": ["column-0"],
                     "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
                      alert("in the function where the final formatting happens")
             return moment(date).format('MMM. D, h:mm A z');
            }
        }], "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]] 
                     
          });
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://oyodev1.cloudapp.net:3000/js/libraries/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.3.0/moment-timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.js"></script>


<div class="container">
 <section>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>TimeZone</th>
              <th width="20%">Location</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 6:19:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 6:17:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thursday, February 19th
    2015, 5:46:18 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:47:56 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
    10:08:02 am</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
    10:09:11 am</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:42 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:14:28 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:14:02 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 6:12:23 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:41 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
         <tr>
    <td>Wednesday, March 4th
    2015, 5:31:33 pm</td>
    <td >Search for the Truth</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Thursday, March 5th 2015,
             10:09:11 am</td>
          <td >Search for the Truth</td>
        </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:40 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:39 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:38 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:37 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:36 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:35 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:34 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:33 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:32 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:31 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:30 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:29 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:28 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:27 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:26 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Friday, January 23rd
    2015, 4:27:25 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Tuesday, January 27th
    2015, 12:32:02 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tuesday, January 27th
    2015, 12:32:01 pm</td>
    <td >Lulus Mac Stuff</td>
   </tr> 
  </table>

</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your corrections. I had not realized I was making these fundamental errors. I am going to run your corrected code on my system and verify the output you have.